# Running multiple time the same docker image

Tags: docker

I was wondering what is happening exactly when I run the same image (already pull locally) multiple time ?

Does it run the dockerfile each time ? (meaning each command in the docker file)

Does it rerun (restart) the container concerned ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does it run the dockerfile each time ?

No: a [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/) will create a container based on the image.
The Dockerfile was used to build the image, but it not involved at runtime.

> Does it rerun (restart) the container concerned?

It create a new container for each `docker run`.

Comment: What if a process inside the container writes some files? Does the change affects only the current *container* or the edit is applied to the *image*?

Comment: @collimarco Only the writable container layer, not the layers from the image: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947168/6309